# IMAP forwarder

Tags: web-services, email, web-applications, imap, forwarding

I'm wondering what is the quickest and most reliable way to forward mail from an IMAP account.

My university does not allow our student-mailbox to forward to a private e-mail account (everybody uses either Gmail or Hotmail here). It's a political thing, not technical. We do have IMAP access to the mailbox. I would like to have a service which downloads the mail through IMAP, and forwards. And it would be nice to scale it, so thousands of students can use it. Eventually, I want to build a public signup page, and have it processed automatically from there.

So far, I've made a decent PHP script which connects, downloads headers and body parts, and ties it all together. I have two problems with that.

1) I'm downloading all kind of parts, and sticking them back together. I hope that every exotic attached file, weird encoded piece of text and every type of header survives this. I'm not even sure I have the complete header.

2) The to: e-mail address becomes the private e-mail address, not the original student e-mail address. I think this is lame, and inconvenient in searching and archiving.

Is the PHP script the way to go? Is there a trick using a particular linux mail service/daemon? Does IMAP have a 'forward' command, I'm missing?

Comment: [getmail](http://pyropus.ca/software/getmail/ "getmail") is another alternative worth considering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to look at [Fetchmail](http://www.fetchmail.info//), as this sounds like the problem it was designed to solve. Fetchmail retrieves mail from POP/IMAP/etc servers and forwards it to SMTP/LMTP/etc servers. Fetchmail has the advantage of a few years and lots of users ironing out problems with various IMAP servers.

Comment: Could you please explain how to configure Fetchmail to forward messages to a gmail account as in the question? From a quick look, it seems to fetches emails for local reading / local processing. Which additional local processing is needed to forward to gmail?

Answer (score 0):

Fetchmail seems like the way to go. I can use PHP to generate/edit a fetchmail command file, so that will cover the public sign-up. I'm looking for a package/script who allready does this.

The Gmail pull only works with POP3, not with IMAP.

Answer (score -1):

If using Gmail you can configure GMAIL to pick up mail from other accounts.

Comment: As far as I know, Gmail can only pick up POP3 mails, not IMAP.

Comment: Yes indeed, Gmail cannot fetch from IMAP accounts.