# PHP IMAP move mail to remote mailbox

Tags: php, imap

About PHP IMAP,

Could someone please help me out? I want to move e-mails from an INBOX to another remote mailbox. In other words, how do I move e-mails from the INBOX of someone@somewhere.com to e.g. INBOX.Unsorted of nobody@nowhere.com?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help, I did a quick search for your problem and there were a bunch of pages that may hold your answer.

**Here there all are:**

- http://egil.biz/migrate-e-mail-over-imap-with-php/
- http://edoceo.com/creo/imap-move

There were more links I found but since I'm a new user I can't post more then 2 =(

I searched for 'php imap move email between addresses' on Google, you'll find more links from there.

Also found this old thread from stackoverflow about the exact same problem: [php - imap - moving emails on antoher account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161775/php-imap-moving-emails-on-antoher-account)

Maybe you'll find more info from the nice folks there =)

Sorry I couldn't give you an answer and only bombard you with links, but, hopefully you'll find one of the links useful.

Comment: Thank you adamj. The first link is what I was looking for. i did have to edit the imap_open() and also add the date_default_timezone_set() for it to work. Now it's doing exactly what I was looking for.